# Способы пропорционального масштабирования блоков

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть блок, растянутый на всю ширину экрана, имеющий в качестве фона художественное изображение. При масштабировании экрана изображение не должно обрезаться и (непропорционально) сжиматься, то есть, насколько могу судить, высота блока должна подстраиваться под его ширину пропорционально размерам фонового изображения.

Вижу два варианта реализации:

1. Вложить фоновое изображение в блок посредством тега `<img/>` так, чтобы изображение само растягивало блок по высоте.
2. Пропорционально менять высоту блока средствами `JavaScript`.

Способа достичь желаемого при помощи `css` я не знаю. Хотелось бы узнать у профессионалов, как это принято (и правильно) делать, возможно, найдутся и другие способы, более приемлемые.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самый известный трюк - задавать пропорции с помощью `height:0` и `padding-bottom`, так называемый **padding-bottom hack**.

Значение для `padding-bottom` расчитывается по формуле:

> высота изображения * 100 / ширина изображения

или

> высота изображения / ширина изображения * 100

---

В данном снипете изображение имеет размеры 1280х720 пикселей, следовательно:

> 720 * 100 / 1280 = 56.25

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background: url(http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1280_720/heihachi_mishima_tekken_7_4k_17496.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Интересное решение, спасибо. На данный момент одно из лучших для меня.

Comment: Единственный вопрос: от чего берется процентное значение для `padding-bottom`? Если `56.25%` поставить свойству `height`, то элемент пропадет с экрана, так как процентное значение `height` берется от высоты родительского элемента.

Comment: @nup в данном случае проценты у padding-bottom высчитываются из ширины элемента. А вот почему так получается я, к сожалению, не знаю :)

Comment: Спасибо. Я думаю, это чудо.

Comment: @Cheg Так прописано [в спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties). А [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004839/6263942) предполагают причину: высота родительского элемента зависит от высоты потомка, поэтому паддинг потомка в процентах от высоты родителя приведёт к бесконечным перерасчётам.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky благодарю за пояснение!

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо ограничить высоту, оборачиваем в `<div class="wrapper">`, а в CSS прописываем классу `wrapper{max-height: значение}`.